# Powershell filtering a property value without expanding the property name

Tags: powershell, dbatools

Is it possible to filter the "Roles" property without using -expandproperty Roles? The first set of statement shows me what I needed except i couldn't filter Roles -eq "db_owner" and users -ne "user3"

```
#import-module dbatools
$servers = server1,server2
Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance $servers -Status Normal | Select SQLInstance,  Name, Owner,Roles, Users 

Results:
SqlInstance : server1
Name        : testdb
Owner       : sa
Roles       : {db_accessadmin, db_backupoperator, db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin, db_denydatareader, db_denydatawriter, 
              db_owner, db_securityadmin, public}
Users       : {user1,user2,user3}
```

If I run another statement
`Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance $servers -Status Normal | select -expandproperty Roles| Where Name -eq 'db_owner'`, the property for db_owner is now called "Name" and it will return the results where "Roles" -eq db_owner.

However, it is now missing the other properties that i needed from the first statement. Do i have to use an array to store the values from each statement then join the results together or is there another way to filter a property value inside "Roles"?

Property of "Roles"
Name  MemberType Definition

---

Roles Property   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseRoleCollection Roles {get;}

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object

Answer (score 1):

Would you be against using `ForEach-Object`?

The below script should return the information you need. You can then filter these results down further if you want.

```
Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance $servers -Status Normal | ForEach-Object -Process {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SqlInstance = $_.SqlInstance
        Name = $_.Name
        Owner = $_.Owner
        Roles = $_.Roles | Where-Object Name -eq 'db_owner'
        Users = $_.Users | Where-Object Name -ne 'user3'
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing against using forEach, part of the script is already doing that. Any idea why i could not do Name = $_Name | WHere-object Name -NotIn 'model,'tempdb','master'   ?

Comment: Apart from maybe missing a "." between $_ and Name i.e. `$_.Name` which could be formatting. If you're not interested in the system databases, you can use `Get-DbaDatabase -ExcludeSystem` and `Get-DbaDatabase` won't return those databases.

Answer (score 0):

```
$servers = server1,server2
Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance $servers -Status Normal | Select SQLInstance,  Name, Owner,Roles, Users | Where-Object { (@($_.Roles)) -contains 'db_owner' }
```

Assuming the Roles property is returning a base array type (I can't check since I don't have that env available atm), you can use the -contains operator to see if a string value is contained in the array.

If the Roles property is a base-Collection type (you can check by using .GetType()), you can explicitly cast Collections to Arrays by wrapping the collection in array notation:  ... `| Where-Object { (@($_.Roles)) -contains 'db_owner' }`

Comment: I tried using -contains operator but that didn't work. The
Property of "Roles"
Name  MemberType Definition                                                            
----  ---------- ----------                                                            
Roles Property   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseRoleCollection Roles {get;}

Comment: @Laurent, the problem is Get-Dbadatabase isn't a standard cmdlet so I cant lookup the datatype being returned by Roles, you need to check it with .GetType()

Comment: Sorry, i kept saving my previous comment before finishing my statement. I have updated the property details in the original post. The getType() is saying this is a PScustomObject

Comment: Ok so it's a Collection-base type, so you should be able to wrap it in @() to convert it to an array to perform the check... try this modification to the where clause i made above -- notice the extra parentheticals in the where clause.

Comment: I tried that too, i got an error.
Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance server1 -Status Normal |  Select SQLInstance, Name, Owner,Roles, Users |  Where-Object { @($_.Roles) -contains 'db_owner' }
Results:
Where-Object : The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the collection: "An exception occurred while executing a 
Where-Object : The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the collection: "An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.".At line:2 char:51
+ ... ner,Roles, Users |  Where-Object { @($_.Roles) -contains 'db_owner' }

Comment: Yeah, wrap it in the extra parenthesis like I edited (@($_.Roles))

Comment: I see the changes you edited. No results came back but after changing the operator to -match, i got the same exact results as in my original post. I guess that's because the condition was met, then it brings back all of the values in the "Roles" column.
I think if i could separate each of the values in "Roles" column in my Select statement, then i can bring back just the value for db_owner